# Строчные или прописные буквы в названиях, состоящих из двух слов?

Tags: орфография

Большие разночтения в написании названий. Как пишутся вторые слова в названиях, например "Уралхим Транс", "Базель Аэро", "Русский Алкоголь", Форум Доноров, "ВТБ Капитал"?

Answer (score 1):

Сейчас приходится писать так, как зафиксировано в уставных документах. А там почти наверняка - с заглавной. Мода нынче такая.

А если рассуждать с позици русского языка, то ваши примеры могут относиться к совершенно разным случаям. Как-то так: *"Уралхим-транс", "Базель-аэро", "Русский алкоголь", Форум доноров, ВТБ "Капитал"*.